# Material Design Ripple Animation into Transition HTML Web

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, smoothstate.js, barbajs

Hello StackOverFlowers!

I found this really awesome animation on jsfiddle.net and would really love to use it in my project.
I'f you follow the link the author, 'internoma', states that it can be used as a page transition if a little Ajax is added.

My question is: What Ajax code do I add in order to make this work?!

I'm extremely lost, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

If you happen to know how to make this working using Barba.js or smoothState.js that would be awesome also since those are to plugins I'd like to dive deeper in learning.

Thanks in advance!

[Link: Material Design Ripple Transition](http://jsfiddle.net/internoma/rv2oyqg0/)

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {var ripple_wrap = $('.ripple-wrap'),
  rippler = $('.ripple'),
  finish = false,
  monitor = function(el) {
    var computed = window.getComputedStyle(el, null),
        borderwidth = parseFloat(computed.getPropertyValue('border-left-width'));
    if (!finish && borderwidth >= 1500) {
      el.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
      el.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
      swapContent();
    }
    if (finish) {
      el.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
      el.style.animationPlayState = "running";
      return;
    } else {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {monitor(el)});
    }
  };

  storedcontent = $('#content-2').html();
  $('#content-2').remove();

   rippler.bind("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd 
      mozAnimationEnd animationend", function(e){
      ripple_wrap.removeClass('goripple');
    });

    $('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
     rippler.css('left', e.clientX + 'px');
     rippler.css('top', e.clientY + 'px');
     e.preventDefault();
     finish = false;
     ripple_wrap.addClass('goripple');
     window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {monitor(rippler[0])});


   });



    function swapContent() {
  var newcontent = $('#content-area').html();
  $('#content-area').html(storedcontent);
  storedcontent = newcontent;
  // do some Ajax, put it in the DOM and then set this to true
  setTimeout(function() {
    finish = true;
  },10);
   }

 });
```

CSS

```
   .ripple-wrap {
     display: none;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: fixed;
     font-size: 0;
     z-index: 1000;
     top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes RIPPLER {
     0%   { border-width: 0; }
     40% { 
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     border-width: 1500px;
     margin-top: -1500px;
     margin-left:-1500px; 
     border-color: #009688;
  }

  41% { 
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     border-width: 1500px;
     margin-top: -1500px;
     margin-left:-1500px; 
     border-color: #009688;
 }
  100% {
     border-width: 1500px;
     height: 2000px;
     width: 2000px;
     margin-top: -2500px;
     margin-left:-2500px;
     border-color: #009688;
   }
 }
  @keyframes RIPPLER {
     0%   { border-width: 0; }
     40% { 
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     order-width: 1500px;
     margin-top: -1500px;
     margin-left:-1500px; 
     border-color: #009688;
  }
  41% { 
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     border-width: 1500px;
     margin-top: -1500px;
     margin-left:-1500px; 
     border-color: #009688;
  }
  100% {
     border-width: 1500px;
     height: 2000px;
     width: 2000px;
     margin-top: -2500px;
     margin-left:-2500px;
     border-color: #009688;
  }
 }
 .ripple {
     display: block;
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     border-width: 0px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: #00796b;
     border-radius: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 300px;
     left: 300px;
     -webkit-animation: none;
     animation: none;
 }
  .ripple-wrap.goripple {
     display: block;
 }
  .ripple-wrap.goripple .ripple {
     -webkit-animation-name: RIPPLER;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     animation-name: RIPPLER;
     animation-duration: 1.5s;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;

   }
```

HTML

```
     <div class="wrap" id="content-area">
     <h1>Material Design Ripple Transition</h1>
     <p>Just playing around to see if I can recreate the Material Design 
     ripple as a page transition in CSS. Click any <a href="#">link</a> in 
     this block of text to load another set of text. The <a 
     href="#">links</a> don't go anywhere yet. They are just <a 
     href="#">hooks</a> to allow you to click somewhere</p>

     <p>The style and animation is entirely CSS so it is smooth. JavaScript 
     is used to add classes at the right time. It also pauses to wait for the 
     content to be replaced, and calculates where to centre the hole. There 
     are two stages to the animation. When a <a href="#">link</a> is clicked 
     the border-width grows very large.</p>

      <p>That's enough reading on this slide. Click a <a href="#">link</a> to 
     load the second slide</p>


     </div>
     <div id="content-2" style="display:none">
     <h2>Slide Two</h2>
     <p>This is the second slide. If you want you can <a href="#">go back to 
     the first slide</a>. The second part of the animation is increasing the 
     size of the element itself in order to create a hole.</p>

      <p>This transition could be used for presentation slides. Using 
     pushState then this could be used as a transition between webpages.</p>


      </div>

      <div class="ripple-wrap"><div class="ripple"></div></div>
```